# Problem upgrading Visual Studio 2008 trial to full version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I had installed the trial version of Visual Studio 2008. I decided to
uninstall it and install the licensed version I just purchased.

However, no matter what I try, the installation will not change from the trial to using my new license. I have completely removed the Visual Studio, but still it will not upgrade.

What can I do beside reformat my machine? (yeah right, like this is gonna happen)

Answer (score 6):

1. Copy the installation files to a folder on the local machine.
2. Find setup.sdb in the "setup" folder and open with some kind of text editor.
3. Find the section "Product Key" and enter the valid key remove the "-" between the number sets..
4. Save the file.

Now here there are 2 options.

1. run the installation program and it will enter "Maintenance mode" and the upgrade option should be available, except for me it still was not.
2. Uninstall  VS 2008 this will only take the core files (re-installation will be much faster). Restart the computer. Re-install from the local files. This option worked for me. I also checked that the correct Product Key was automatically entered.

My final step was to burn a new disk with the modified setup for the future.

Hope this helps.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall the trial version. Instead, choose Change/Remove in Add/Remove Programs. When the installer launches in maintenance mode, you'll have an option to change the registration key instead of uninstalling.

Comment: he just said in the previous answer comment that he did that all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a trial version installed, but you should check under the "Help" menu for an option like "Purchase" or "Register".

Comment: This seems about right - I don't think you should have to reinstall to upgrade, you should be able to install your license into the trial

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are removing all its components from Add/Remove programs -control panel.

And after reinstall go to Add/Remove programs, press on change remove and make sure the key is there.

Comment: I did all that and even when there is no sign to the trial version it still install my register version with the trial key